# Switch value to decide which subclass to use

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have an abstract class Payment, which is implemented by several PaymentTypes

```
    public abstract class Payment
    {
        protected int contract;
        public Payment(int contract)
        {
            this.contract = contract;
        }

        public abstract bool Aprove();
    }
```

and then, two classes which implement it

```
public class PaymentA : Payment
{
    public PaymentA(int contract) : base(contract)
    {
        this.contract = contract;
    }

    public override bool Aprove()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
public class PaymentB : Payment
{
    public PaymentB(int contract) : base(contract)
    {
        this.contract = contract;
    }

    public override bool Aprove()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now, I need to create PaymentA or PaymentB depending on a form field

```
static void Main(string[] Args)
{
    int contract = 1;
    Payment payment;
    switch (rbtPaymentType)
    {
        case (int)EPaymentTypes.A:
            payment = new PaymentA(contract);
            break;
        case (int)EPaymentTypes.B:
            payment = new PaymentB(contract);
            break;
    }

    payment.Aprove(); //Use of unassigned local variable
}
```

I have two questions:

1 - Is it well constructed so I can call payment.Aprove() no matter which type of payment it is?

2 - How can I do the method call if the object is not initialized? I get error "Use of unassigned local variable"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 - Is it well constructed so I can call payment.Aprove() no matter which type of payment it is?

Yes, for simple application it's ok. If you want to make it a little better you can use simple factory like so:

```
public class PaymentFactory
{
    public Payment CreatePayment(int rbtPaymentType, int contract)
    {
        switch (rbtPaymentType)
        {
            case (int)EPaymentTypes.A:
                return new PaymentA(contract);
            case (int)EPaymentTypes.B:
                return new PaymentB(contract);
            default:
                throw new Exception("Unknown payment type");
        }
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] Args)
    {
        int contract = 1;
        Payment payment = null;
        int rbtPaymentType = 1;
        PaymentFactory paymentFactory = new PaymentFactory();
        payment = paymentFactory.CreatePayment(rbtPaymentType, contract);
        payment.Aprove();
    }
}
```

Whenever you switch over something to create a new instance you should think about encapsulating it in factory. This way you don't have to repeat the same switch in other place if you want to create another instance of Payment.

> 2 - How can I do the method call if the object is not initialized? I get error "Use of unassigned local variable"

You can assign it to null like I've shown in the example above.

Btw. you don't have to assign contract member in constructors of PaymentA and PaymentB since base class does it for you.